# How to filter IQueryable whole tree?

Tags: c#, where-clause, iqueryable

i have `Contact` query which contains `Communication` sub-query which contains `CommunicationExtension` sub-query

```
static class Program
    {
        public class Contact
        {
            public int ContactID { get; set; }
            public List<Communication> Communications { get; set; }
            public DateTime? DeletionDate { get; set; }
        }

        public class Communication
        {
            public int CommuncationID { get; set; }
            public List<CommunicationExtension> CommunicationExtensions { get; set; }
            public DateTime? DeletionDate { get; set; }
        }

        public class CommunicationExtension
        {
            public int CommunicationExtensionID { get; set; }
            public int AreaCode { get; set; }
            public DateTime? DeletionDate { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IQueryable<Contact> q = GenerateData();
            IQueryable<Contact> result =
                q.Where(c => c.DeletionDate == null && 
                    c.Communications.Where(co => co.DeletionDate == null && 
                        co.CommunicationExtensions.Where(ce => ce.DeletionDate == null));
        }



        private static IQueryable<Contact> GenerateData()
        {
            return new List<Contact>
                       {
                           new Contact
                               {
                                   ContactID = 1,
                                   DeletionDate = DateTime.Now,
                                   Communications =
                                       new List<Communication>
                                           {
                                               new Communication
                                                   {
                                                       CommuncationID = 1,
                                                       DeletionDate = DateTime.Now,
                                                       CommunicationExtensions = 
                                                       new List<CommunicationExtension>
                                                           {
                                                               new CommunicationExtension
                                                                   {
                                                                       CommunicationExtensionID = 1,
                                                                       AreaCode = 5,
                                                                       DeletionDate = null
                                                                   }
                                                           }
                                                   },
                                               new Communication
                                                   {
                                                       CommuncationID = 2,
                                                       DeletionDate = null,
                                                       CommunicationExtensions = 
                                                       new List<CommunicationExtension>
                                                           {
                                                               new CommunicationExtension
                                                                   {
                                                                       CommunicationExtensionID = 2,
                                                                       AreaCode = 55,
                                                                       DeletionDate = DateTime.Now
                                                                   }
                                                           }
                                                   }
                                           }
                               },
                           new Contact
                               {
                                   ContactID = 2,
                                   DeletionDate = null,
                                   Communications =
                                       new List<Communication>
                                           {
                                               new Communication
                                                   {
                                                       CommuncationID = 1,
                                                       DeletionDate = null,
                                                       CommunicationExtensions = 
                                                       new List<CommunicationExtension>
                                                           {
                                                               new CommunicationExtension
                                                                   {
                                                                       CommunicationExtensionID = 3,
                                                                       AreaCode = 54,
                                                                       DeletionDate = null
                                                                   }
                                                           }
                                                   },
                                               new Communication
                                                   {
                                                       CommuncationID = 2,
                                                       DeletionDate = DateTime.Now,
                                                       CommunicationExtensions = 
                                                       new List<CommunicationExtension>
                                                           {
                                                               new CommunicationExtension
                                                                   {
                                                                       CommunicationExtensionID = 4,
                                                                       AreaCode = 5565,
                                                                       DeletionDate = null
                                                                   }
                                                           }
                                                   }
                                           }
                               }
                       }.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
```

When i try to build it, i get the error:

Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

on line:

```
IQueryable<Contact> result =
                q.Where(c => c.DeletionDate == null && 
                    c.Communications.Where(co => co.DeletionDate == null && 
                        co.CommunicationExtensions.Where(ce => ce.DeletionDate == null)));
```

I need to filter all data that is not deleted (`DeletionDate == null`). In my scenario there is ~200 tables in database, each table contains nullable field `DeletionDate`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:

```
c.Communications.Where(co => co.DeletionDate == null && 
    co.CommunicationExtensions.Where(ce => ce.DeletionDate == null)
```

Those two lines don't return a boolean, so your `Where` call doesn't know what to do with it. Are you wanting any Contact that has at least one non-deleted `Communications` and `CommuincationExtensions`? If so, then change the `Where` calls to `Any` and it should work. However, note that when actually dealing with your `Contacts` you'll still need to filter out any deleted `Communications`/`CommunicationExtensions` as the relationships will just get you the related records no matter what. In other words, `contact.Communications` will return all `Communications` related to that `Contact`, and `comm.CommunicationExtensions` will return all `CommunicationExtensions`, so you'll still need to filter out any deleted records whenever you deal with them.

Comment: I want all `Contacts` `Communications` and `CommunicationExtensions` that aren't deleted. Such related tables could be much more than 3 like in this example. And i need to write this in a multiple `Where()`. I can't use `ToList()` because it will load all unnecessary data. Later this data is binded to to view threw single `Contact`. More data is loaded when view need it from `Communication` or `CommunicationExtensions`.